# How can I link Image Source = "?" with Value from DataTable (path image) in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am looking to change the value `Source = "img / Best / 1.png"` for the `DataGrid` cell that I clicked on, with a click, a button, any option.

How can I bind the value in the `DataGrid` cell loaded from `DataTable`? I've tried different options and nothing worked. It is complicated WPF for a beginner.

Here is a concept photo:

[image: Here is a concept photo]

I have cross-posted this [to the Russian Stack Overflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1118424/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-source-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-image-datatemplate-%D0%B2-datagrid-wpf-c) site.

Here's an example of implementing my idea in [Windows Forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms):

https://github.com/grebtsew/Patterns-Maker

```xaml
<Window.Resources>
    <viewModel:DataRowViewConverter x:Key="drvc" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ATemplate">
        <Image x:Name="MyImage" Source="img/Best/1.png"></Image>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>


<DataGrid x:Name="MyGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn" CanUserAddRows="True" SelectedCellsChanged="MyGrid_SelectedCellsChanged" SelectionUnit="Cell" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
</DataGrid>
```

```csharp
DataGrid MyGrid = new DataGrid();
System.Data.DataTable MyDataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
MyDataTable.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(string));
MyDataTable.Columns.Add("Col2", typeof(string));
MyDataTable.Columns.Add("Col3", typeof(string));
MyDataTable.Columns.Add("Col4", typeof(string));
MyDataTable.Columns.Add("Col5", typeof(string));
// dt.Columns.Add("2 тип А", typeof(A));

MyDataTable.Rows.Add("test", "img/Best/1.png", "img/Best/1.png", "img/Best/1.png");
MyDataTable.Rows.Add("TestString");

Items = MyDataTable;
this.DataContext = this;
```

Comment: put all of the code up into a GitHub repository and Ill take a look. I cant tell what the problem is when you only show part of the code

Comment: Ill try and get to it as soon as I can, but it may not be today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll admit this is something of a fail for WPF, but you are almost there. The big problem is that as soon as you use a template column, it becomes hard to get hold of the column index, which you need to bind to the data table.

Anyway, along with your converter, it works if you make `ATemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ATemplate">
    <Image 
        DataContext="{
            Binding RelativeSource={
            RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCell},
            Converter={StaticResource drvc}}" 
        Source="{Binding}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

(Yuk! And yes, this is about as bad as WPF gets. It's a horrible introduction to the framework. If possible avoid autogenerated columns. Although I appreciate that this might not be possible, WPF is actually a good GUI framework).

Comment: I am very grateful to you, you saved me from torment. I wonder why there are no detailed manuals on such issues on MSDN. You are a programming guru.

Comment: Happy to help. DataTables are rarely used in new projects, they are more of a WinForms paradigm, that is probably why there isn't so much written about them in a WPF context.